# Rails 4 - Custom create method, assign association manually after looking up object by name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to modify the `create` method of my controller to custom build this object.

The scenario is a modal window displays a form which has an autocomplete text field that loads in platform names via AJAX, then the user submits the form, the `create` method looks up the `Platform` by the name in the text box, and adds it to the `current_user.game` collection...

I have a simple `has_many` relationship from `Game` to `Platform`

```
1    def create
2        platform = Platform.where(:short_name => params[:platform])
3     
4        game = Game.new(game_params)
5        game.platform << platform
6        current_user.games << game
7        render :nothing
8    end
```

I am getting an error `undefined method '<<' for nil:NilClass` on line 5.

I don't know if this is how this should be done... How should I try to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had the association wrong in my models (forgot to add it) and also I had a `platform` column of type `string` in my `Game` table instead of a `platform_id` column of type `integer.

After updating that I began getting the an `ActiveRecordTypeMismatch` error which it was expecting the type `Platform` but found `ActiveRecord::Record::Association` (or something like that).

Also apparently when assigning to the `belongs_to` side of an association use `=` instead of `<<`.

Below is the updated working controller `create` method

```
game = Game.new(game_params)
game.platform = Platform.where(:short_name => params[:platform]).first
current_user.game << game
render :nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `s`?

```
game.platforms << platform
#------------^-------------
```

Comment: This is the belongs_to part of the relationship, thank you though.

Comment: @SnareChops `belongs_to` does not defined `<<` use `=`. See [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to) for docs.